# Database Design: How do I handle tracking goals vs. actuals over time?

Tags: database, database-design, graphql

This isn't exactly a programming question, as I don't have an issue writing the code, but a database design question.  I need to create an app that tracks sales goals vs. actual sales over time.  The thing is, that a persons goal can change (let's say daily at most).

Also, a location can have multiple agents with different goals that need to be added together for the location.

I've considered basically running a timed task to save daily goals per agent into a field.  It seems that over the years that will be a lot of data, but it would let me simply query a date range and add all the daily goals up to get an goal for that date range.

Otherwise, I guess I could simply write changes (i.e. March 2nd - 15 sales / week, April 12th, 16 sales per week) which would be less data, but much more programming work to figure out goals based on a time query.

I'm assuming there is probably a best practice for this - anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Put a **date range** on your goals.  The start of the range is when you set that goal.  The end of the range starts off as max-collating date (often 9999-12-31, depending on your database).

Treat this as "until forever" or "until further notice".

When you want to know what goals were in effect as of a particular date, you would have something like this in your `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE effective_date <= @AsOfDate
  AND expiry_date > @AsOfDate
...
```

When you change a goal, you need two operations, first you update the existing record (if it exists) and set the `expiry_date` to the new as-of date.  Then you insert a new record with an `effective_date` of the new as-of date and an `expiry_date` of forever (e.g. '9999-12-31')

This give you the following benefits:

- Minimum number of rows
- No scheduled processes to take daily snapshots
- Easy retrieval of effective records as of a point in time
- Ready-made audit log of changes

Comment: Hi @JoelBrown - my only question with this is about the complexity of then running the reports.  If I run a historical report over the course of a year, I then have to find each time that someone changed their goals, calculate the time between that and the next change, and then calculate the total for that time period, then do the same for all other time periods in the year and add them up.  If I simply kept a daily total, I could just query all daily goals in the time period, add them, and be done.  So I just want to confirm it is your belief that keeping the database simpler is better?

Comment: @JustinHandley you'll often find that the best data structure for data maintenance is very different from the best data structure for reporting.  The term "data warehouse" refers to a database structured for reporting.  In this kind of database, the rules of normalization go out the window because a data warehouse is basically read-only.  It represents history and so it can't be changed (this is an over simplification) 

It depends on your goals.  If you need to do both, then you might need both kinds of data structures to meet all your needs with simple, reliable  code.